# How refresh part of page after submit?

Tags: html, angularjs, ajax

I develop function for create user, when I create user all the page refresh,but i want just the tables refrech automatically, just the table refresh and not all the page, how to correct my problem ?

```js
function JSalert() {
  swal({
    title: "opération effectuée avec succès",
    text: "",
    icon: "success",
    confirmButtonColor: "#C13232"
  });
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
      location.reload(true);
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body" ng-style="{'height': '500px','width':'643px'}">
  <form name="myForm1" id="myForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label name="refe" class="col-form-label">Email:</label><span style="color: red;">*</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="refee" ng-model="registration.Email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="tire7" class="col-form-label">Adress:</label><span style="color: red">*</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="titree" ng-model="registration.Adress" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="tire75" class="col-form-label">Mobile:</label><span style="color: red">*</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="titree" ng-model="registration.Mobile" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="site" class="col-form-label">Site:</label><span style="color: red">*</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="titre12" ng-model="registration.Site" required>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnsave" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="JSalert()" ng-click="signUp()" style="margin-left: 350px" disabled>Done
                    </button>
```

Comment: So, other than stating that if you want to only update a part of the page that that would involve using ajax, rather than a `location.reload()`, your question mentions updating tables, but your question does not show any tables in the snippet.

Comment: i'm sorry, yes i want refresh just part of page

Comment: Looks like you need to use AJAX Technology !

Answer (score 0):

For refreshing only particular table without reloading page, call the service(for the data that you are displaying in the table) once again after success signup.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand your answer

Comment: on successful submit of form you are displaying that data in table for that you are reloading the page right?

Comment: yes is true, when the click of button done(submit) the page refresh , but i have just part of page